# How to Exclude some js types when adding prototype to Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

As soon as I add the below code to my html page, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (constrname) {
    if(this.constructor.name===constrname){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
} has no method 'exec'
```

This is the prototype that causes the bug:

```
Object.prototype.isInstanceOf=function(constrname) {
    if(this.constructor.name===constrname){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};
```

Adding prototype seems break jQuery .

Can i exclude some types when define new prototypes to Object type . For example , exclude : jQuery type ,...

i tried the following code but it is in vain :

```
Object.prototype.isInstanceOf=function(constrname) {
      if(!(this instanceof jQuery)){
              //write here code
      }
}
```

Comment: No.  Instead, make it non-enumerable.  Better yet, don't do that at all.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the conditions that cause this error? I'd think jQuery is well-written enough not to break on something like that.

Comment: @SLaks thanks for answer;However, who should i make it non-enumerable , and how ?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. The entire point of prototypal inheritance is that objects on the prototype are inherited by *every* descendant. You cannot remove them.